# How to login on on-premise SharePoint(local SharePoint) in IOS?

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem

Trying to make an app for local sharepoint login and access sharepoint list data in IOS app. I have try to login and pass parameter as username and password but give error **401 unauthorized**.
I tried to login. Only one response send **401 unauthorized** by server.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You problem of 401 is an authentification problem.

You need to use **REST API** and **OData** of SharePoint (hope you are in 2013).
And do all you stuff with this API (authentification, query list ...). There is not API in IOS for SharePoint.

Have a look at this topic in the MSDN who explain how to do that : [Build mobile apps for other platforms using SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj870858.aspx)

Or check this exemple from codeproject : [Development of iPhone client application for SharePoint 2013](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571996/Development-of-iPhone-client-application-for-Share)

I'm not a IOS dev, so I will not past.

Hope this exemple will help you